# Need help finding bug, if string input is composed all of same character one output character is corrupt

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management, cstring

`reverser()` reverses a cstring (not in place). 99% of the time it works but some input corrupts it for example it appears if aStr2[] is assigned a string made up of the same character it will have an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* reverser(const char *str);

int main()
{
    char aStr[] = "aaa";
    char aStr2[] = "cccccc";
    printf("%s %s", aStr, aStr2);
    char* tmp = reverser(aStr2);//tmp now has garbage
    printf("\n%s", tmp);
    printf(" %s", aStr2);
    return 0;
}


char* reverser(const char *str)
{
    char* revStr = (char*)malloc(strlen(str));
    int i;
    for(i = strlen(str)-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
        revStr[strlen(str)-1-i] = str[i];
}
    return revStr;
}
```

Gives

```
aaa cccccc
cccccc9 cccccc
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.068 s
Press any key to continue
```

Notice the 9 that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Let's pretend I'm browsing with images turned off. Now how am I supposed to know the output? Post text instead of screenshots.

Comment: [Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C strings malloc (output)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249734/c-strings-malloc-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this malloc to strlen(str) + 1 , plus 1 for '\0'

```
char* revStr = (char*)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

and after the for loop

```
revStr[strlen(str)+1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you don't put the string terminator in your reversed string. All strings in C are actually one extra character that isn't reported by `strlen`, and that is the character `'\0'` (or plain and simple, a zero). This tells all C functions when the string ends.

Therefore you need to allocate space for this extra terminator character in your `malloc` call, and add it after the last character in the string.

There are also a couple of other problems with your code, the first is that you should not cast the return of `malloc` (or any other function returning `void *`). Another that you have a memory leak in that you do not free the memory you allocate. This last point doesn't matter in a small program like the one you have here, but will be an issue in larger and longer running programs.

Comment: Where would free be called? It can't go before `return`

Comment: @Celeritas By the function calling `reverser`, when you're done with the string.

Comment: If the variable being assigned the return value of `reverser` is inside a loop does it need to be free'd each iteration?

Comment: @Celeritas Yes it does, or you have a leak.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't null-terminated your reversed string. You need to set the final index of revStr[] to 0.